# Control de usuarios SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una app web que tiene 3 tipos de usuarios: El Admin(yo), los empleados y los clientes. La cosa es que los empleados, tienen los permisos para editar las tablas de los usuarios, no es que me haga gracia la idea, pero es lo que me piden. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma (algún log de la base de datos, app o algo) que me permita saber quién ha borrado/escrito sobre alguna tabla.

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que MS SQL Server implementa SQL Server Audit que permite auditar grupos de eventos y eventos individuales de nivel de servidor y de base de datos. Puedes leer este doc publicado por Microsoft : [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el log de transacciones (Transaction Log) se queda esa información. Por ejemplo, puedes consultarlo para ver los `DELETE` con:

```
USE <NombreBBDD>
GO
SELECT 
    [Transaction ID],
    Operation,
    Context,
    AllocUnitName

FROM 
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
WHERE 
    Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
```

De las varias filas que te va devolver la consulta, en AllocUnitName encontrarás el nombre de tabla de la que se ha hecho un `DELETE`. En [Transaction ID] encontrarás la clave que usaremos en la clausula `WHERE` de la siguiente consulta (realmente podrias hacerlo todo en una sola consulta, ya que siempre la lanzamos contra fn_dblog ... que por otro lado devuelve en torno a las 100 columnas):

```
USE <NombreBBDD>
GO
SELECT
    Operation,
    [Transaction ID],
    [Begin Time],
    [Transaction Name],
    [Transaction SID]
FROM
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE
    [Transaction ID] = '0000:000004ce'
AND
    [Operation] = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
```

Esta consulta te devuelve en [Transaction SID] el identificador del usuario que ha hecho el delete y por último:

```
USE MASTER
GO   
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(0x0105000000000005150000009F11BA296C79F97398D0CF19E8030000)
```

Esto nos devolverá el login que corresponde a ese SID.

La información la he sacado de [aquí](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3090/how-to-find-user-who-ran-drop-or-delete-statements-on-your-sql-server-objects/) y puedes ampliarla [aquí](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3076/how-to-read-the-sql-server-database-transaction-log/) (ambos en inglés).

### Otros métodos

Personalmente yo lo haría de otra manera, se me ocurren al menos 3:

- Controlarlo a nivel aplicación, es decir cada vez que desde la aplicación vayas a hacer una operación de modificación sobre la tabla, dejes constancia en otro sitio (log o tabla) de quien ha hecho el que (y a que hora, etc...). Aquí incluso puedes solicitar información al usuario de porque hace el cambio.
- También desde la aplicación, pero solo desde el SQL que ejecutes, hacer que todas las sentencias SQL que trabajan con esas tablas, te dejen constancia en otra tabla de la operación que se está realizando y del usuario que la realiza. Esto lo puedes hacer tanto a nivel de sentencias SQL que uses en la aplicación, como en los procedimientos almacenados si es eso lo que utilizas.
- A nivel de tabla, es el planteamiento que a priori más me gusta, si quieres auditar tablas, puedes poner triggers en el momento de definirlas, que te hagan operaciones de auditoria en los inserts, updates y deletes. Una vez hecho eso, el resto de la aplicación podrás desarrollarlo igual que si no tuvieras los triggers, pero estos te irán dejando constancia de lo que se va haciendo en cada tabla (y quien lo va haciendo). Para saber como funciona te dejo [este](http://www.dataprix.com/blog-it/bases-datos/sql-server-auditoria-datos-personalizada-mediante-triggers) y [este](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/es/tecnicas-de-auditoria-de-bases-de-datos-sql-server/) enlaces (ambos en español).

Comment: Intentaré hacerlo con el 3er método que me propones, y si veo que no me sale, con el primero. Gracias por todo